# Visual Basic Deployment Script

Tags: vb6

I am working with a VB 6.0 project. The project uses the packaging and deployment wizard. Where are deployment scripts saved when you use this wizard?

Comment: Wow... I didn't think there was anybody doing VB6 stuff in 2013...

Comment: I'm in a big company (over 150 developerls in North America) and there is a LOT of development in VB6. Its virtually impossible to convert a huge system that took decades to develop to newest programming language. And in a year or two, when .SomethingElse comes out, convert to it once more? Thats why you still see old technology like VB6 or Cobol around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The deployment script is normally saved as a file alongside the project file with a `.pdm` extension.

The setup itself is created in whatever folder you told it to along with the support files required to rebuild the cabinet file.

To edit the deployment script, you can use a simple text editor like Notepad, or you can just re-run the wizard. I believe it uses the existing script as a base (but it's been ~10 years since I last used it).